# How do I convert a hash to an array or arrays?

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I can not figure out how to convert a hash into a multidimensional array. I have the following hash produced from roo after reading an Excel spreadsheet:

```
{[1, 1]=>"string-1", [1, 2]=>"string-2", [1, 3]=>"string-3", [1, 4]=>"string-4", 
[1, 5]=>"string-5", [1, 6]=>"string-6", [1, 7]=>"string-7", [2, 1]=>"string-1", 
[2, 2]=>"string-2", [2, 3]=>numeric-1, [2, 4]=>numeric-2, [2, 5]=>"string-3", 
[2, 6]=>"string-4", [2, 7]=>numeric-3, [3, 1]=>"string-1", [3, 2]=>"string-2", 
[3, 3]=>numeric-1, [3, 4]=>numeric-2, [3, 5]=>"string-3", [3, 6]=>"string-4", 
[3, 7]=>numeric-3, ... etc}
```

I need to convert this to:

```
[["string-1", "string-2", "string-3", "string-4", "string-5", "string-6", "string-7"], 
["string-1", "string-2", numeric-1, numeric-2, "string-3", "string-4", numeric-3], 
["string-1", "string-2", numeric-1, numeric-2, "string-3", "string-4", numeric-3],
... etc]
```

I tried the following but it is just copying everything into one array, rather than embedded arrays:

```
2.upto(input.last_row).each do |row|
  ((input.first_column)..(input.last_column)).map{ |col| 
    $rows << input.cell(row, col) if col != 5 and col <= 10}.join(" ")
end
```

I have searched for the answer for hours but can not find a solution.

The following ended up being my workable solution:

```
((xlsx.first_row)..(xlsx.last_row)).each do |row|
  ((xlsx.first_column)..(xlsx.last_column)).each do |col|
    $tmp_row << xlsx.cell(row, col) if col != 5 and col <= 10
  end
remove_newlines_from_strings($tmp_row)
$rows_sheet_0 << $tmp_row
$tmp_row = []
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 1.9+ then you can take advantage of ordered Hashes with something like this:

```
a_of_as = spreadsheet.group_by { |k, v| k.first }.map { |k, v| v.map(&:last) }
```

If you're not certain that the Hash will be built in the proper order, then you could force the "sort by coordinate" like this:

```
a_of_as = spreadsheet.sort_by  { |k, v| k }
                     .group_by { |k, v| k.first }
                     .map      { |k, v| v.map(&:last) }
```

I'm assuming that there aren't any gaps in the grid but that seems like a safe assumption when dealing with a spreadsheet.

For example (reformatted for compactness):

```
>> pp spreadsheet
{[1, 1]=>"string-1", [1, 2]=>"string-2", [1, 3]=>"string-3",  [1, 4]=>"string-4",  [1, 5]=>"string-5", [1, 6]=>"string-6", [1, 7]=>"string-7",
 [2, 1]=>"string-1", [2, 2]=>"string-2", [2, 3]=>"numeric-1", [2, 4]=>"numeric-2", [2, 5]=>"string-3", [2, 6]=>"string-4", [2, 7]=>"numeric-3",
 [3, 1]=>"string-1", [3, 2]=>"string-2", [3, 3]=>"numeric-1", [3, 4]=>"numeric-2", [3, 5]=>"string-3", [3, 6]=>"string-4", [3, 7]=>"numeric-3"}

>> pp spreadsheet.group_by { |k, v| k.first }.map { |k, v| v.map(&:last) }
[["string-1", "string-2", "string-3",  "string-4",  "string-5", "string-6", "string-7"],
 ["string-1", "string-2", "numeric-1", "numeric-2", "string-3", "string-4", "numeric-3"],
 ["string-1", "string-2", "numeric-1", "numeric-2", "string-3", "string-4", "numeric-3"]]

>> spreadsheet2 = Hash[spreadsheet.sort { |(ka,va),(kb,vb)| kb <=> ka }]
>> pp spreadsheet2
{[3, 7]=>"numeric-3", [3, 6]=>"string-4", [3, 5]=>"string-3", [3, 4]=>"numeric-2", [3, 3]=>"numeric-1", [3, 2]=>"string-2", [3, 1]=>"string-1", 
 [2, 7]=>"numeric-3", [2, 6]=>"string-4", [2, 5]=>"string-3", [2, 4]=>"numeric-2", [2, 3]=>"numeric-1", [2, 2]=>"string-2", [2, 1]=>"string-1",
 [1, 7]=>"string-7",  [1, 6]=>"string-6", [1, 5]=>"string-5", [1, 4]=>"string-4",  [1, 3]=>"string-3",  [1, 2]=>"string-2",  [1, 1]=>"string-1"}

>> pp spreadsheet2.sort_by { |k,v| k }.group_by { |k, v| k.first }.map { |k, v| v.map(&:last) }
[["string-1", "string-2", "string-3",  "string-4",  "string-5", "string-6", "string-7"],
 ["string-1", "string-2", "numeric-1", "numeric-2", "string-3", "string-4", "numeric-3"],
 ["string-1", "string-2", "numeric-1", "numeric-2", "string-3", "string-4", "numeric-3"]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion. I tried it and am getting the following error: undefined method `group_by' for #<Excelx:0x48fdf20>

Comment: @user1411496: `spreadsheet` should be your Hash, not your actual spreadsheet.

Comment: The spreadsheet is my hash ... input.default_sheet = input.sheets[0] (from roo). My hash is then "input" ...

Comment: If `input.is_a? Hash` is true then `input.group_by { ... }` should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
h = {[1, 1]=>"string-1",[1, 2]=>"string-2",[1, 3]=>"string-3",[1, 4]=>"string-4",
[1,5]=>"string-5",[1, 6]=>"string-6",[1, 7]=>"string-7",[2, 1]=>"string-1",
[2, 2]=>"string-2",[2, 3]=>"numeric-1",[2, 4]=>"numeric-2",[2, 5]=>"string-3",
[2, 6]=>"string-4",[2, 7]=>"numeric-3",[3, 1]=>"string-1",[3, 2]=>"string-2",
[3, 3]=>"numeric-1",[3, 4]=>"numeric-2",[3, 5]=>"string-3",[3, 6]=>"string-4",
[3, 7]=>"numeric-3"}

h.each_with_object(Hash.new([])){ |m,res| res[m.first.first] += [m.last] }.values

#=>[["string-1","string-2","string-3","string-4","string-5","string-6","string-7"],
#=> ["string-1","string-2","numeric-1","numeric-2","string-3","string-4","numeric-3"],
#=> ["string-1","string-2","numeric-1","numeric-2","string-3","string-4","numeric-3"]]
```

Thanks to **mu is too short**'s hint I can rewrite it a little bit:

```
h.each_with_object(Hash.new{|h,k|h[k]=[]}) do |m,res| 
  res[m.first.first] << m.last 
end.values
```

Comment: You might want to note why you're not falling into the usual `Hash.new([])` trap.

Comment: Look at what `[1].each_with_object(Hash.new([])) { |i,h| h[i] << i }` does and you should see it.

Comment: The construction h[i] << i really doesn't work and I'm working on it but in my answer I used h[i] += [i] construction, so what is the trap in my answer?

Comment: `h[i] << i` does work, the problem is that `Hash.new(x)` simply returns `x` when there is a missing, it doesn't add the key to the Hash. `res[m.first.first] += [m.last]` works for two reasons: (1) it is the same as `res[m.first.first] = res[m.first.first] + [m.last]` so the assignment will create the key in `res` and (2) `Array#+` creates a new array rather than modifying either of its operands so you're actually doing `res[x] = [] + [m.last]` and the default value doesn't get changed. Perhaps looking at `[1,2].each_with_object(Hash.new([])) { |i,h| a = h[i]; a << i; h[i] = a }` will help.

Comment: Thanks, I really was mad because of default value, I thought it should create a key in Hash. I think h[i] += i construction is better then a=h[i]; a<<i: h[i]=a.

Comment: `a=h[i]; a<<i: h[i]=a` is just to demonstrate the "don't modify the default value" trap, there are actually two traps with `Hash.new([])`.

Comment: I've updated with Hash.new{|h,k|h[k]=[]} block, I think it will resolve the problem

Comment: I forgot to ask what is the second trap?

Comment: `res[m.first.first] += [m.last]` works due to the assignment (`=`) which creates the key and the duplication (`+`) which avoids altering the default. Traps: (1) `Hash.new(x)` doesn't create keys when they're accessed, it just returns `x` when the key isn't there, (2) be very careful about accidentally altering the default value since it isn't duplicated when used, it just returns the reference.

Comment: For some reason, I keep getting "undefined method, errors ... undefined method `each_with_object' for #<Excelx:0x48fdf20>

Comment: If Excelx is your new type of object, then you should mix in the Enumerable module into your class (include Enumerable) and implement each method. Read the doc http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html